# Copy files of specific type but prevent overwriting files

Tags: bash, macos, sh

I need to copy all files of a specific type to a folder, which I'm doing like this:

```
find ./ -name '*.gql' -exec cp -prv '{}' '/path/to/dir/' ';'
```

But if there are two files with a identical name, although located in different subfolders, some files would be overwritten.

Is it possible to keep all files, which are copied? Maybe renaming the copied file or is it possible to keep the folder structure in the target directory?

Comment: You could look into `-b`/`--backup` if your `cp` supports it (GNU `cp` does).

Comment: @BenjaminW. I am on a mac machine and it is not supported by the cp which I'm using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c.f. https://ss64.com/osx/cp.html : `Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option`...`its use is strongly discouraged, as it does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's.` You can use `-n` to prevent overwrites, but more complex logic will likely require custom code.

```
dest=/path/to/dir
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename # read null-delimited list from find 
do basename="${filename##*/}"
   if [[ -e "$dest/$basename" ]] 
   then ctr=0
        while [[ -e "$dest/$basename.$((++ctr))" ]]; do : ; done # find available name
        mv "$dest/$basename" "$dest/$basename.$ctr"
   fi
   cp -pv "$filename" "$dest/$basename"     
done < <( find ./ -name '*.gql' -type f -print0 ) # null-delimit
```

Comment: If you are absolutely sure there will be no files with "weird" names you can simplify the `find`/`read`,  but this will work either way.